# How do I tell Entity Framework to set a 1:1 FK entry when the child model being deleted has no 1:many property to the parent?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a parent object as follows:

```
public class Event
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public Interest? Interest { get; set; }
}

public class Interest
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    // no List<Event> Events { get; set; }
}
```

So each `Event` object has 0 or 1 `Interest` objects. Many Events can point to the same Interest.

When I delete an Interest object, I want every Event.Interest in the database where that Interest is the deleting Interest, to be set to null. Is there a way to declare this in EF?

Or do I need to read all those Event objects, set their Interest to null, and then save them?

Or is there a way, via Entity Framework to pass a SQL statement that says to set the underlying Event.InterestId to null for all that are presently set to the being deleted Interest.Id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the cascading option when configuring the relationship - see the [Cascade Delete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/cascade-delete) doc. Something like the following:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Event>()
    .HasOne<Interest>(e => e.Interest)
    .WithOne()
    .HasForeignKey<Interest>("EventId")
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull) // Or DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull
    .IsRequired(false);
```

Notes:

- > Many Events can point to the same Interest.

  That means one-to-many though setup will not change that much:

  ```
  modelBuilder.Entity<Event>()
       .HasOne<Interest>(e => e.Interest)
       .WithMany()
       .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull) // Or DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull
       .IsRequired(false);
  ```
- [EF Core: One-to-one relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/one-to-one)
- [EF Core: One-to-many relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/one-to-many)
- I recommend to expose the navigation property either way (which also will allow to apply `[DeleteBehavior(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)]` attribute)